# How do I get a file's compressed size in R?

Tags: r, file, compression

Suppose I have a zip file filled with files. How do I retrieve the compressed size of each file? R's base function `file.info()` and `file.size` return the original size, not the compressed size.

Comment: Run `unzip -v` on the file and parse the results.

Comment: `unzip(filename, list=TRUE)` returns a `data.frame` with columns `Name` (the internal file names), `Length` (each file's original size in bytes), and `Date`.